# Using next js for a static website

Tags: reactjs, jsx, next.js

error - React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
There were quite a few questions with the same context, I tried those solutions but have not found a solution.

The Navbar of the website is what is giving me the error. There is a section over the Navbar which renders properly, when I try to render the Navbar below it throws the error.

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Head from '../components/head'
import Download from '../components/nav'
import NavBar from '../components/header'
import Footer from '../components/footer'
import htmlContent from 'html-loader!../legacy/index.html'



const Homepage = () => (

  <div>
 <Head />
 <Download/>
<NavBar />
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlContent}} />
    <Footer />
  </div>

);
export default Homepage
```

The footer shows properly, head tag is for all the meta data etc(also works). Github link to all the code is-https://github.com/yohanelly/website-jsx/tree/master/components

Comment: Your [`header.js`](https://github.com/yohanelly/website-jsx/blob/master/components/header.js) seems to have some syntax issues

Comment: Yes I realized that and corrected the syntax issues. The li tags had issues. But the error still persists. Any ideas? I mean, the rest of the components work fine.

Comment: Did I miss anything any other syntax errors? @GabyakaG.Petrioli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the whitespace between the `Link` and the `a` tag.

```
<Link href="#"> <a className="menu-links features">Features</a></Link>
```

should be either

```
<Link href="#"><a className="menu-links features">Features</a></Link>
```

or

```
<Link href="#">
    <a className="menu-links features">Features</a>
</Link>
```

Read the [Children in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) section of the React docs for more info.

Comment: Yes, also I missed out a small syntax error. Any other good resources for jsx please send them. Thanks alot!!